# Reducing the size of oracle database docker image

Tags: oracle, docker

Oracle provides [docker images for its database](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles), is there a way to reduce the size of the docker image down from the current `5.06GB`? That size is obtained building with the defaults. Tested on `12.1.0.2-se2`.